# Python: numpy.ndarray split

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I have `array(['USD/EUR', 'nan'], dtype='<U32')` that I want to split so that I get `[USD, EUR]`. How can this be done?

The .split function is not working for me.

Comment: `.split` is a string method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about the element `'USD/EUR'`, then just extract it, then use `split()`, specifying that the split should be on the `'/'` character:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['USD/EUR', 'nan'], dtype='<U32')
b = a[0].split('/')
print(b)
```

Comment: what if the list grows and I have ['USD/EUR', nan, 'USD/CHF', ...]. Is there a way to split them all without specifying the position of the string?

Comment: How exactly do you want the final data to be organized? A new array containing `np.array(['USD', 'EUR', 'USD', 'CHF'])`? Or perhaps a list of 2-tuples like this: `[('USD', 'EUR'), ('USD', 'CHF')]`?

Answer (score 0):

`np.char` module has a bunch of functions that apply string methods to a `U` dtype array.  It's not faster than doing the equivalent list comprehension, but may be more convenient.

```
In [19]: arr = np.array(['USD/EUR', 'nan'])
In [20]: arr
Out[20]: array(['USD/EUR', 'nan'], dtype='<U7')
In [21]: np.char.split(arr, '/')
Out[21]: array([list(['USD', 'EUR']), list(['nan'])], dtype=object)
```